# What is the rationale behind concluding x has a factor of 3 if it is an integer in this equation?

Tags: factoring

This is from the solutions manual to the art of problem solving volume 1 (I have attached the image below). In the equation mentioned, I see that x equals three due to 2^3*3^3 being equal to 6^3;however, I am not seeing why the statement the authors made regarding x having 3 as a factor if it is an integer is true. Can someone please explain how to prove this statement for this equation/the rationale behind it? thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is an integer, $(2x)^x$ can be prime factored and, by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, can only have the one factorization $2^33^3$. So, the base number $2x$ must be a multiple of $3$.

Comment: It is not clear to me how one deduces 2x is a multiple of 3 just from the prime factorization- what if the power to which 2x is raised is of such a nature as to render a factor of three unnecessary in its equality with the factorization?

Comment: @God The power to which $2x$ is raised is an integer. Therefore $(2x)^x$ is just a product of the integer $2$ and the integer $x$ multiplied repeatedly. It’s an integer factorization of $216.$ The whole point of unique prime factorization is that if the final product has a factor of $3$, **any** integer factorization will also have a factor divisible by $3$. The factor $2$ is not divisible by $3$, so $x$ must be.

Answer (score 0):

It is a standard result that if $p$ is prime, then for any positive integers $a$ and $n$, $p | a \iff p | a^n$ (where $b|a$ means $b$ divides $a$). This comes from the fact that if $p|ab$ then either $p|a$ or $p|b$, which you can apply inductively to $p|(a \times a^{n-1})$.

So if $x$ is a positive integer, then $(2x)^x$ is an integer power of $2x$, so then $3|(2x)^x \implies 3|2x$, and since $3 \not | 2$ we must have $3|x$.